# Syntax Error when changing the index of a Series

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to change the index of a Series. The indices are `Date`s. `cashflow_series` is the Series, and I am just trying to add a certain number of months to this date by using `replace(month = cashflow_series.index[k].month + dict_no_months_between_payments[count])` on the index and use this to replace the previous index date. However, I get the error `SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax`.

```
index_here = cashflow_series.index[k]
cashflow_series.index[k] = cashflow_series.index[k].reindex(index=index_here.(replace(month = cashflow_series.index[k].month + dict_no_months_between_payments[count])))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one set of parentheses too many:

```
index_here.(replace
           ^
```

Remove that one and its closing match.

Comment: Would you know how I could do what I am attempting by just changing a **single index** of a Series, as `reindex` would change all the indices?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do that.